# Swap string order in one line or swap lines order in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to swap place of 2 or more regex strings in one line or some lines in a txt file in powershell.
In npp i just find `^(String 1.*)\r\n(String 2.*)\r\n(String 3.*)$` and replace with `\3\r\n\1\r\n\2`:

```
String 1 aksdfh435@#%$dsf
String 2 aksddfgdfg$dsf
String 3 aksddfl;gksf
```

Turns to:

```
String 3 aksddfl;gksf
String 1 aksdfh435@#%$dsf
String 2 aksddfgdfg$dsf
```

So how can I do it in Powershell? And if possible can I use the command by calling `powershell -command` in cmd?

Comment: You can use RegEx in PS just as you can elsewhere. Read the file, make your changes, output to a new file, delete the original file/overwrite the original, or read the file in raw, make the change, output as a new file, delete the original/overwrite the original data.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically exactly the same in PowerShell, eg:

```
$Content = @'
Unrelated data 1
Unrelated data 2
aksdfh435@#%$dsf
aksddfgdfg$dsf
aksddfl;gksf
Unrelated data 3
'@

$LB = [System.Environment]::NewLine
$String1= [regex]::Escape('aksdfh435@#%$dsf')
$String2= [regex]::Escape('aksddfgdfg$dsf')
$String3= [regex]::Escape('aksddfl;gksf')
$RegexMatch = "($String1.*)$LB($String2.*)$LB($String3.*)$LB"
$Content -replace $RegexMatch,"`$3$LB`$1$LB`$2$LB"
```

outputs:

```
Unrelated data 1
Unrelated data 2
aksddfl;gksf
aksdfh435@#%$dsf
aksddfgdfg$dsf
Unrelated data 3
```

I used `[System.Environment]::NewLine` since it uses the default line break no matter what system you're on. Bound to a variable for easier to read code. Either

```
\r\n
```

or

```
`r`n
```

would've worked as well. The former if using single quotes and the latter (using backticks) when using double quotes. The backtick is what I use to escape `$1`, `$2` and so on as well, that being the format to use when grabbing the first, second, third group from the regex.

I also use the `[regex]::Escape('STRING')` method to escape the strings to avoid special characters messing things up.

To use file input instead replace $Content with something like this:

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path 'C:\script\lab\Tests\testfile.txt' -Raw
```

and replace the last line with something like:

```
$Content -replace $RegexMatch,"`$3$LB`$1$LB`$2$LB"  | Set-Content -Path 'C:\script\lab\Tests\testfile.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell it is not very different.

The replacement string needs to be inside double-qoutes (`"`) here because of the newline characters and because of that, you need to backtick-escape the backreference variables `$1`, `$2` and `$3`:

```
$str -replace '^(String 1.*)\r?\n(String 2.*)\r?\n(String 3.*)$', "`$3`r`n`$1`r`n`$2"
```

<sup>This is assuming your $str is a single multiline string as the question implies.</sup>